# VSTS Docker Release step

Tags: ubuntu, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm confused as to what is required to push my project docker container onto my production server from docker repository using VSTS.

I have done the following steps:

1. Created my application with Dockerfile
2. ran the build on VSTS to create a docker container
3. Pushed that container into my hub.docker.io account.

I am manually able to log ontu my linux (ubuntu 16) box and pull the container down and run it 100%.

I would like to create a release step/action within VSTS to do that last manual step for me. Is this possible? If so can someone explain the steps or point to a good guide.

NB: The web box is my own private VPS box, no major cloud provider, just straight ubuntu with docker installed.

Comment: You have a SSH based key access to the box?

Comment: I can set one up, not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different option now. You can use a tool like Ansible to create a script and run on your remote server.

Or you can create a script on remote server which does the whole update process

**/var/myapp/update.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
docker pull myimage:latest
docker stop myapp
docker rm myapp
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name myapp myimage:latest
```

Setup a key based SSH session and then use below

```
ssh -i keyfile <user>@<Server> bash -c "/var/myapp/update.sh"
```

**Edit-1**

For the tty issue change the ssh command to

```
ssh -t -i keyfile <user>@<Server> bash -c "/var/myapp/update.sh"
```

For the sudo issue you can add your user to docker group

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <user>
```

Comment: Ok where do I run the 'ssh i keyfile ... ' from ? Keeping in mind it's a release process running on VSTS.

Comment: See if this helps https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-linux

Comment: I think I'm close except for two issues: 1) 'docker stop previouscontainer', there is no such token as previouscontainer, should I replace with something else. 2) running the script, I have set everything up including the VSTS agents but now I have permission problems running the scripts. It's telling me that there is no TTY for sudo, which there isn't but not sure what to do with it, still working on it.

Comment: @user281921, see my edits. You can run the image as a named image

Comment: STill getting permission errors:ssh -i id_rsa_nopass ********@demoweb bash -c "/var/myapp/update.sh"
##[error]bash: /var/myapp/update.sh: Permission denied    Not sure what info I can supply as thats all it gives me. I have tried both the private and public key files (Both are no-password).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153494/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user281921).